# Inserting into a Table if one Distinct Value is not Present

Tags: sql-server

My table contains these values

```
Name VARCHAR(50),
Program VARCHAR(50),
 Branch VARCHAR(30),
TotalP INT,
 TotalN INT)
```

I've been trying to INSERT records into this table IF the Name doesn't already exist. This has probably already been answered on here but when I type something into the search it comes up with 7000+ results and I looked through 100+ and still didn't find the answer. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't worried about concurrency, the following would work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Name = @Name
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YourTable (Name, Program, Branch, TotalP, TotalN)
    VALUES (@Name, @Program, @Branch, @TotalP, @TotalN)
END
```

The problem here would be that if two processes attempted to add the same `name` at the same moment... both would pass the `IF NOT EXISTS` check, and then both would `INSERT`.

To prevent this, you can either add a unique constraint to the `name` column, which would cause one of the inserts to fail, or you could lock the table in your `NOT EXISTS` check using `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)`, which would reduce concurrency but not raise any errors.

EDIT:

If the values that you want are from a `SELECT` statement, the following would work:

```
INSERT INTO YourDestinationTable (Name, Program, Branch, TotalP, TotalN)
SELECT st.Name, st.Program, st.Branch, st.TotalP, st.TotalN
FROM 
    YourSourceTable st
    LEFT JOIN YourDestinationTable dt
        ON dt.Name = st.Name
WHERE 
    dt.Name IS NULL
    -- Add in any other conditions for YourSourceTable here...
```

This will insert the row from `YourSourceTable` if the row is not found in `YourDestinationTable`... implemented using a `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` check.

This has the same caveats as before... if two processes run this statement simultaneously, you can end up with duplicate `name` values; either add a unique constraint on `name`, or perform a `(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` on the row in the destination table that you're testing for existence inside of a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 
            YourSourceTable st
            JOIN YourDestinationTable dt WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
                ON dt.Name = st.Name
        -- WHERE 
            -- Add in any other conditions for YourSourceTable here...
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO YourDestinationTable (Name, Program, Branch, TotalP, TotalN)
        SELECT Name, Program, Branch, TotalP, TotalN
        FROM YourSourceTable st
        -- WHERE 
        -- Add in any other conditions for YourSourceTable here...
    END
COMMIT
```

Comment: This may be obvious but, how would I do this if the values I want to insert are from a SELECT statement? Thanks for your help

Comment: You are awesome!! I can't believe that escaped me :) Thanks!